# Save variable number of form fields generated after DOM load with AJAX to backend database

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Modal window on my app which loads in order data using AJAX and updates the HTML content of the Modal with the result of the AJAX response which is in JSON format.

One of the variables I get in my JSON response is `var number_units = 6;` which can be any number value.

What I need to do is take the value of `var number_units` and generate an HTML Form with 2 `dropdown selection elements` which will hold an option value for each row.  A row is from the `var number_units`

So in this example `var number_units = 6` so I would need to create 6 rows of selection options in this modal.

I have some JavaScript in my demo below which creates my 6 rows of options.

What I need help with is the next stage.  I need to make an AJAX request to save the 6 option rows to a database.

The Form consist of:
 `var number_units` x 2 selection options per unit row.
+
2 hidden form fields at the end of the form to hold the order ID and order item ID value.

The 2 selection options on each unit row are:
- a selection with option 1-4
- a selection with option "none", "argon", and "neon"

I have 2 options for saving this to my Database.

1. Convert into JSON string and save into 1 column on the order DB table.  (keep in m,ind this data never will need to be searched or anything.  It will only be used to show in my modal and pre-populate the selection options in the form above)
2. Save each unit row set of options into a new database table where each unit row is a new row/record in the DB.

In this case, either one would work just fine.

---

**What I need help with:**

My code below generates my row of options for each number stored in my JavaScript variable `number_units`.  In this demo it is 6 so I create 6 unit rows.

Each unit row has 2 selection option fields to select a number between 1 and 4 and the other to select a value of "none", "argon", or "neon"

So I need help with getting the selected values when a button is clicked on and making an AKAX request with the data.

I then need to either convert into JSON and update order DB table and insert this into 1 column on that table or else insert each unit row into a new record  on a new DB table.

I also need help in pre-populating my form with the selected values if they had previously been saved to the DB already.

I know this seems a bit complex so I can use any help I can get please.

The way the app works is in another part of the app a user selects how many units and order has which is where `var number_units` is populated with a number.

Next when they open the Modal window with the order data, it will need to shows the options for each unit based on the number of units they had selected.

I need to save that selections to DB and next time the order Modal is opened, it will need to have there selections selected already.

---

**What the unit rows look like**

[image]

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/j5vL8nrj/

**HTML**

```
<form id="form">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// create HTML element and append to parent element
function create(htmlStr) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild) {
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////




// set some vars for use later in hidden form field
var orderId = 123456789;
var orderItemId = 123;

// numjber of rows to create our form selectiopn options for
var number_units = 6;
var unitCounter = 1;

// Get form
var form = document.getElementById('form');


// Iterate number of times set in var number_units
for(var i = 0; i < number_units; i++){

  // Create select element with options 1-4 and assign a class name
  var select1= document.createElement('select');
  select1.className = 'form-control input-sm';

  var s1o1 = document.createElement('option');
  s1o1.value = '1';
  s1o1.text = '1';
  var s1o2 = document.createElement('option');
  s1o2.value = '2';
  s1o2.text = '2';
  var s1o3 = document.createElement('option');
  s1o3.value = '3';
  s1o3.text = '3';
  var s1o4 = document.createElement('option');
  s1o4.value = '4';
  s1o4.text = '4';

  // Append the option elements to the select element
  select1.appendChild(s1o1);
  select1.appendChild(s1o2);
  select1.appendChild(s1o3);
  select1.appendChild(s1o4);  


  // Create select elements for "neon/argon" option and assign it a class name
  var select2= document.createElement('select');
  select2.className = 'form-control input-sm';

  // Create 4 option elements with value and text
  var s2o1 = document.createElement('option');
  s2o1.value = 'none';
  s2o1.text = 'none';
  var s2o2 = document.createElement('option');
  s2o2.value = 'neon';
  s2o2.text = 'neon';
  var s2o3 = document.createElement('option');
  s2o3.value = 'argon';
  s2o3.text = 'argon';

  // Append the option elements to the select element
  select2.appendChild(s2o1);
  select2.appendChild(s2o2);
  select2.appendChild(s2o3);

  // Create a span element with the number of row it is on.
  // in this demo it will be between 1 and 6
  var span1Fragment = create('<span>Unit '+unitCounter+'</span> ');
  form.appendChild(span1Fragment);

  // Append the 2 select elements to the form element
  form.appendChild(select1);
  form.appendChild(select2);

  // create a <br> element between each row of options
  var breakFragment = create('<br>');
  form.appendChild(breakFragment);

  // increment row counter by 1 each iteration
  unitCounter++;

} // end for loop

// create 2 hidden form fields to holder order ID and order item ID and add to end of form.
var hiddenFormField1 = create('<input type="hidden" name="order-id" id="order-id" value="'+orderId+'"><input type="hidden" name="order-item-id" id="order-item-id" value="'+orderItemId+'">');
form.appendChild(hiddenFormField1);
```

Comment: Looks like you thought out what you need to do. I would say follow that up with research. 1. How do you make a form? What are the necessary things for a form to be submitted? Hint: you need a input (submit type) to submit the form. 2. Once submitted, research how to bind the submit event and grab the correct values for your json. 3. Use ajax to send the data. Looks like you already know how to use ajax right?

Comment: What are you using for your backend? Have you looked at Parse.com? Their Javascript API would make this super easy to achieve